# Concatenating layouts during runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

I am thinking to create a layout whose height is much more than the screen height. OK say, the parent layout is LinearLayout and it is set to provide a vertical scrollbar automatically.

Inside the parent layout, there are many controls (listview, gridview, listboxes, editboxes etc). To make it easier for design, can I put listview in one xml, gridview in one xml, listbox in one, editbox in one etc and then later use some defined function to concatenate and allocate them all in the parent layout ?

If this is not possible, how can I design a layout that has many controls allocated that design screen can't fit at design time ?

Comment: Yes you can make different xml file and include then in your parent layout.

Comment: How can that be ? What method to call ?

Comment: If you make xml file then you have just call **<include layout="@layout/urlayoutname" >
                </include>** in your main xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xml_common.xml
```

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/common_topheader_width"
    android:background="@drawable/topheaderfor9patch" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/xml_common_header_imageLogotop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/common_left_right_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/qarrow" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
Main_view.xml
```

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/xml_common" />

</LinearLayout>
```

you can set different images as per your choice set in runtime of common view.